# How to encode a string with a 56-character key with Triple Algorithm?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, base64

Give me a 56-character key given in base 64 format. I have to encode this string "terminalid; order_id; price" with TripleDes(ECB,PKCS7) in python3.

I enter the corresponding modules and decrypt the key. But the problem is the key length.

```
import base64
from Crypto.Cipher import DES3
def encrypt_DES3(terminal_id,order_id,amount):
"""

:param terminal_id: String-for example: EUDuTQrp
:param order_id: integer- for example: 123456
:param amount: integer - for example: 60000
:return: encrypt "terminal_id;oreder_id;integer"
"""
key =base64.b64decode("YTAzZTYyNDNiMTljMzg0YzYxY2NhMGU4NjU1ODc2N2FkYTAwMGJiOQ==")
text = terminal_id + ';' + str(order_id) + ';' + str(amount)
def pad(text):
    while len(text) % 8 != 0:
        text += '='
    return text

plain_text = pad(text)
cipher = DES3.new(key, DES3.MODE_ECB)
my_export = cipher.encrypt(plain_text)
return my_export
```

I have problem with key length. Thank you for advising.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#18>", line 1, in <module>
encrypt_DES3('EUDuTQrp',123456,60000)
File "<pyshell#17>", line 17, in encrypt_DES3
cipher = DES3.new(key, DES3.MODE_ECB)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Crypto/Cipher/DES3.py", line 
113, in new
return DES3Cipher(key, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Crypto/Cipher/DES3.py", line 
76, in __init__
blockalgo.BlockAlgo.__init__(self, _DES3, key, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Crypto/Cipher/blockalgo.py", 
line 141, in __init__
self._cipher = factory.new(key, *args, **kwargs)
ValueError: Invalid key size (must be either 16 or 24 bytes long)
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use AES instead. This module is provided only for legacy purposes.

https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/des3.html

Comment: I want to write a payment gateway. To send data and receive token, they said to be sent with this encryption. Do you have a better module or better method to implement this algorithm?